# How to filter columns of one table by values given as rows in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in MySQL. I would like to select columns from *main_table* which are given as rows in *cols_filter* table (it is a small table which can be edited at any time).

**main_table:**

```
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+
| Col_A  | Col_B  |  Col_C  | Col_D | Col_E |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+
| Apple  | 585416 | Monday  |   0   |   Y   |
| Banana | 857463 | Sunday  |   1   |   N   |
| Orange | 852147 | Friday  |   0   |   N   |
| Plum   | 753951 | Sunday  |   1   |   Y   |
| Peach  | 448691 | Monday  |   0   |   N   |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+-------+
```

**cols_filter:**

```
+--------+
| names  |
+--------+
| Col_A  |
| Col_B  |
| Col_E  |
+--------+
```

**Expected output:**

```
+--------+--------+-------+
| Col_A  | Col_B  | Col_E |
+--------+--------+-------+
| Apple  | 585416 |   Y   |
| Banana | 857463 |   N   |
| Orange | 852147 |   N   |
| Plum   | 753951 |   Y   |
| Peach  | 448691 |   N   |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

I was trying to create a subquery with GROUP_CONCAT to have all rows from *cols_filter* as comma seperated values in one line:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(names) AS Columns
FROM cols_filter

+---------------------+
|       Columns       |
+---------------------+
| Col_A, Col_B, Col_E |
+---------------------+
```

... and using it as a list in main query instead of putting certain column names there, but it did not work.

I was not able to find a similar question here. Any ideas?

Comment: This requires dynamic SQL.  I might suggest that the need for this suggests a potential flaw in the application.

Answer (score 1):

Framing SQL cannot be dynamic within database itself, but can be achieved through little programming on top. You can use any programming language(python/java/scala) to generate the SQL dynamically and fire the query to the database.